# Is it possible to give a whole table one specific ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

New at this, so bear with me here..

I'm trying to create a playlist table which is comprised of songs from a song table.

So, I've got a basic setup like this.

```
           songs
|song_id | title   | artist   | 
|   1    | MyTitle | MyArtist |
```

That table would theoretically hold all of the available songs. And the playlists would be made from those available songs.

That table looks like

```
            playlists
| id    | playlist_name | playlist_songs  |
```

But I'm not sure how to make the playlist_songs table. I assume it would look something simple like this:

```
       playlist_songs
| id  | song_id (foreign key) |
```

Where it's just a bunch of rows each referencing the `song` table. Problem with this is that I don't know how to "target" a specific table like that.

The other option would be storing all of the foreign song_ids "flatly" in a single field.

```
    playlist songs
| id   |     song_ids           |
|  1   | 1, 5, 4, 2, 11, 30, ...|
|  2   | 44, 43, 22, 1, 2, 40...|
```

However, everything I've read about databases thus far points to this being a poor solution, as it's  not in normal form.. but.. I don't know how to put it in normal form!

Comment: Since playlist songs is set-valued, it would be a good idea to give it its own relation.  Your playlist_songs table would be a good implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `playlist_songs` should be a relation table:

```
       playlist_songs
| playlist_id (foreign key) | song_id (foreign key) |
```

since a song can belong to more than one playlist and a playlist can have more than one song.

Then about your concern, the reference for a specific table you're looking for is ensured in the definition of the foreign key.
If you look closely in the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE `playlist_songs`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `playlist_songs_playlist` FOREIGN KEY (`playlist_id`) REFERENCES `playlist` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `playlist_songs_song` FOREIGN KEY (`song_id`) REFERENCES `song` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

the table is referenced along with the field to map the parents and children records.

Answer (score 0):

Your three table structure is the correct way to do it.  With a little deviation from what you had:

```
songs
|song_id | title | artist |

playlists
| playlist_id | playlist_name |

playlist_songs
| playlist_id | song_id |
```

Then to get the information for the songs in a particular playlist you would use ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59bb8/1/0)):

```
SELECT pl.playlist_name, s.artist, s.title
FROM playlists AS pl
  JOIN playlist_songs AS pls ON pl.playlist_id = pls.playlist_id
  JOIN songs AS s ON pls.song_id = s.song_id
WHERE pl.playlist_id = 1
```

You definitely do NOT want to: store all of the foreign song_ids "flatly" in a single field.  It is better to normalize the data.  But, just looking at that method, you would have to write unnecessary complex queries to parse out the songs from that field.